# If I grab a paramenter out of the query string, is it URL decoded?

Tags: .net, asp.net

In .NET if I do something like:

```
string temp = Request.QueryString["myKey"];
```

is the value in temp already URL decoded?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, it is.